# Email alias causes Outlook rule to trigger on 'sent to' condition even if primary email address is in To field

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, office365, email-filter

I have an odd situation involving an Outlook Exchange catch-all email address with aliases, and Outlook rules.

The rule states that if the email is sent to a secondary email address (secondary@example.com), then to move the email to a folder. However, if someone sends the email to my primary email address (primary@example.com), the rule is still triggered. This is the rule:

[image: Outlook Rule - address]

As the mailbox is a catch-all inbox (creating using [these instructions](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30462.office365-catch-all-mailbox.aspx)), I don't require the secondary email address to be an alias for the purpose of receiving emails to that address. I created the alias merely for the purpose of being able to send *from* the secondary email address when sending an email in Outlook.

Historically, this has never been a problem for me because I have only ever needed to *receive* emails to the secondary email address. I did not have that address specified as an alias, and the rule has always functioned as expected - it only triggered if the To field explicitly contained that address. Now that I need to *send* emails from that email address, I have to add it as an alias which is now causing the rule to trigger when the secondary email address is **not** in the To field, but the primary email address is.

I contacted Microsoft Support about this, and they are investigating whether this is by design. But is there any way I could achieve what I had before which is that the rule only triggers when the secondary email address is in the To field, but with it now added as an alias?

I have tried using a different rule trigger to look for specific words in the recipient address (see below), but this doesn't work (I believe it looks at the display name, not the email address itself).

[image: Outlook Rule - words]

Any insight or ideas appreciated, even if that's that's just to say it's not possible in which case I'll just remove any aliases used in rules, and just add them temporarily whenever I need to send an email from such an address.

Answer (score 0):

Try having the rule check the message header for the alias, it works for me.
Here are the steps:

Select "With Specific Words in Message Header"
[image]

Click Specific words and add your Aliases

[image]

Hope that may help you!